# Asterisk(ver 11.22.0) EPOCH variable not updated

Tags: global-variables, asterisk

I tried to use **EPOCH** asterisk  variable in order to take a timestmap  to perform some calculation during a context execution.

What I get is that during a context exectuion the EPOCH variable doesn't change value. 
In the follwoing example, EPOCH will ahve the same value at 1st line and last line.

```
[TEST-CONTEXT] 
exten => 8001,1,NoOp(${EPOCH})
exten => 8001,2,Do SOMETHING 
exten => 8001,3,Do SOMETHING 
exten => 8001,4,Do SOMETHING 
...
exten => 8001,n,NoOp(${EPOCH})
```

Is this correct? If this is the expected behaviour how can I get during a call processing , in acontext the timestamp to clauclate for example the elapsed time?

Asterisk was behaving correclty , the "do something" actions were buggy such that they completed within few ms so no changes were reported in EPOCH variable value

Comment: Asterisk was behaving correclty , the "do something" actions were buggy such that they completed within few ms so no changes were reported in EPOCH variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You dialplan is actually correct, ${EPOCH} will print the time of the execution of that priority. I've tested it with my Asterisk v.11.22:

Using this dialplan:

```
exten => 997,1,Noop(${EPOCH})
 same => n,Wait(10)
 same => n,Noop(${EPOCH})
 same => n,Hangup
```

This is the result I get:

```
-- Executing [997@from-internal:1] NoOp("SIP/1001-000047fa", "1478657120") in new stack
-- Executing [997@from-internal:2] Wait("SIP/1001-000047fa", "10") in new stack
-- Executing [997@from-internal:3] NoOp("SIP/1001-000047fa", "1478657130") in new stack
-- Executing [997@from-internal:4] Hangup("SIP/1001-000047fa", "") in new stack
```

As you can see, the time difference is actually the 10 second I added as a wait.

Edit: Just saw you are running the same version as me. Have you considered that all the priorities and the final epoch could be running in the same second?

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I just realized that the "do SOMETHING" actions where complete so fast (becasue other bugs) so there was not enough time to appreciate a change in the EPOCH  .

Comment: Good to know. Can you mark this question as solved, please?